# Issue with Nested query execution in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am trying out the following query. I am writing this to get list of documents, for each document i need to run some logic to get the tags list. Using this tag list i update the document with tags list obtained.

**I am getting the tags list for 'updateAndPrint' function as blank**. I guess its an issue with promise coming into picture.

Here is the query:

```
DB.todoTable.find()
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function (err, todos) {
        var tags = [];
        for (var todo in todos) {
            var text = todos[todo].text;
            var id = todos[todo]._id;
            console.log(text);
            tags = getTagsList(text);

            (function updateAndPrint(id, tags) {
                DB.todoTable.update({_id: id}, {$addToSet: {tags: {$each: tags}}},
                    function (err, numberUpdated, result) {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        (function printResult(id) {
                            DB.todoTable.findOne({_id: id})
                                .exec(function (err, todo) {
                                    if (err) throw err;

                                    console.dir(todo.tags);
                                });
                        })(id);
                    });
            })(id, tags);

        }
        console.dir(tags);
    });
```

How can i get this query to run. Or is there a better way to do the same logic.

#### Edit

'tags = getTagsList(text)' has to be performed before i run update operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) instead of update and set the option `{new: true}`.

**UPDATE**

You can pass your function to be called as a callback to your `findTags`, so instead `findTags(text)` you will have `findTags(text, callback)`, where your callback will be the `updateAndPrint` function. So when you got all your data in the `findTags` you can call the `callback`.

Comment: How can i obtain taglist while using findAndModify. 'tags = getTagsList(text)' has to be performed before i run update.